# Efficient Way of making a set of tuple in which the order of tuple doesn't matters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, tuples

I want to make a set of tuples in which the order of tuples shouldn't matter.
For eg.- If the tuples I want to add is :

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,1)]
```

It should output like this:

```
{(1,2),(1,3)}
```

Is there any efficient way of doing this in python?

Comment: Turn the tuples into [`frozensets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the problem with that is if the tuples have repetitions like  `l = [(1,1,2),(2,1,1)]` then the tuples itself would be changed as frozen sets(and normal sets) do not allow repetition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can apply `sorted` and then `tuple`, followed by conversion to `set`:

```
res = set(map(tuple, map(sorted, L)))

print(res)

{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```

**Explanation**

There are a couple of good reasons why you should not convert each tuple to `set` as an initial step:

1. Tuples `(1, 1, 2)` and `(1, 2)` would become equal after conversion to `set`.
2. Even in the case where we are considering tuples of length 2, we would be adding an assumption that `tuple({(1, 2)})` and `tuple({(2, 1)})` are equal. While this may be true, it would be considered an implementation detail, since `set` is considered to be unordered.

**Function composition**

Function composition is not native to Python, but if you have access to the 3rd party [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library you can avoid nested `map`:

```
from toolz import compose

tup_sort = compose(tuple, sorted)

res = set(map(tup_sort, L))
```

Comment: may I ask why you remove the other solution with just sets? actually i tought that would be better

Comment: @Netwave, So using `set` then `tuple` assumes `{1, 2}` converted to a tuple will always give `(1, 2)`. While this *may* be true, it should not be assumed as sets are unordered. If sets were *randomly* ordered, you could have one `{1, 2}` set give `(1, 2)` and another give `(2, 1)`. Using `sorted` + `tuple` has one less assumption.

Comment: @Netwave i think the best reason *not* to use sets (or frozensets) here is that duplicates are removed e.g. `{1,2,2} == {1,2}`

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the tuples:

```
l = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,1)]
res = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), l))
print(res)
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers all work! I'm just going to post mine here because I'm a beginner and I love to practice.

```
mainSet = set()
l = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,1)]

for i in l:

    if tuple(sorted(i)) not in mainSet:

        mainSet.add(tuple(sorted(i)))

print(mainSet)
```

Gives back

`{(1, 2), (1, 3)}`

Whether you want to use this or not is up to you! The other answers are much more shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension, too:

```
l=[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1)]
res={ tuple(sorted(t)) for t in l }
print(res)
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```